# Use the comparison to show $∑1/\log(n)n^2$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I understand how to use the comparison test when it comes to $\sum\dfrac{\log(n)}{n^2}$ but not for the question below? 
Use $\log(n)>1$ for $n\geq2$ and the comparison test to show that the series
$\sum\dfrac{\log(n)}{n^2}$
converges.

Comment: well $$\frac1{\log(n)n^2}<\frac1{n^2}$$ for $n\geq 3$, and $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ converges

Answer (score 1):

If it is $\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}$, here is a way to do it :

$$\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}=\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/2}}\,\frac1{n^{3/2}}$$

Since $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/2}}=0}$, there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}^\star$ such that :

$$\forall n\ge N,\,\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/2}}\le1$$

Hence :

$$\forall n\ge N,\,\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\le\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$